# Reading string in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C programming, and I wondered how it worked to read strings in an array. Here is the example that confuses me:

```
int main(void) {
    char array[100] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}; 
    // we add the '\0', so it doesn't read the entire array

    array[98] = 'x'; 
    // define that at index [98] there is character 'x'

    char *p, *q; 
    // creates pointers

    p = array; 
    // pointer p now points toward the address of the array, 
    // which is index [0]

    printf("%s", p); 
    // Will print everything until a '\0' is reached, 
    // so print 'abc'

    printf("%s", (p + 2)); 
    // p is now pointing at the address of index[2], 
    // so print 'c'

    q = &array[5]; 
    // pass the address of index[5] to q

    printf("%s", q); 
    // what is printed out?
}
```

I thought that the last line `printf("%s", q);` would print everything in the array until it reaches a `\0` because we specify `%s` in `printf`. So, the `'x'` would be printed, but when I run the program, nothing gets printed. Why is that?

I get

```
abcc
```

Could you explain me step by step what happens when I read my program? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: You didn’t define what’s after array[3], so I believe the standard says the rest must be initialized with 0. So array[5] is zero, or a zero length string.

Comment: ``printf("%s", q);`` is basically ``printf("");``. You try to print a zero length tring.

Comment: So, I was wrong to think that the way C prints String is that it prints every cell(memory space) until a `\0` is reached?

Comment: Note, `char array[100] = {'a','b','c','\0'};` is exactly the same as `char array[100] = "abc"`.

Comment: Since the array is a block-scope variable (with automatic storage duration), the values of the uninitialized part of the array are indeterminate. If the array had been declared at file-scope or with the `static` keyword (static storage duration), it would have been guaranteed to be initialized to zeroes.

Comment: I think that @NisseEngström is correct although I've seen various compilers try to "help" the user by (for example) pre-initializing stack variables with `0xcc` so that you can recognize uninitialized data in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your array, only the first 4 bytes were properly initialized. The rest of the array, so the other 96 bytes were initialized to 0, So when printing starting at index 5, it is being treated as an empty string

Answer (score -2):

At line number 2
I.e
array[98]='x'; //define that at index [98]
This is wrong declaration as well as initialization of character array.So this line will not work.
For writing character array, the syntax is :---
data_type name[size]

printf("%s", p); //Will print everything until a '\0' is reached, so print 'abc'

printf("%s", (p+2)); //p is now pointing at the address of index[2], so print 'c'
That's all remaining will not printed

Comment: The statement `array[98] = 'x'; ` isn't attempting to declare a variable. It's assigning a character to one of the members of the existing array.

Comment: But you can't assign value to a character array like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Statements of the form `array[index] = value;` are fairly straightforward. The only thing that's tricky about this particular example, I think, is that the value to be stored in the array is provided as a character constant, that is, `'x'`. This expression evaluates (on most modern machines) to the ASCII value of the lowercase `x` character. And generally speaking when manipulating strings, that's exactly the sort of value you'd want to store.